# Is there any way to ask the browser to ask the user to allow pop ups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications, popup

What I want to do is, with the user's permission, open several new tabs with different locations. I know there is a way for the browser to ask to know the user's location, or ask the user to allow notifications... is there a way to ask the user to allow pop ups or do they have to do it manually?

I'm betting most users don't know how to do it manually, so that's the issue. I provide links on the page to the sites, so they can click on them one at a time; but I would also like to provide an "open all" button that will create multiple new tabs.

I know that pop ups suck and I hate them too, but if a user wants to open 5 or 6 new tabs, shouldn't we be able to give them an easy way to allow it?

Comment: No, there's no way. The user has to enable it manually. You can kindly ask the user on your page to do so. Some browsers allow them by default, some don't, but most users have pop-up blockers anyway.